# Powershell statement in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Is there a way to do this PowerShell statement in C#

```
$myvariable = New-PSSessionOption -SomeParameter -AnotherParameter -YetAnotherParameter
```

I know how to run commands and add parameters (PowerShell.AddCommand etc), but I'm missing something that lets me do an entire statement.

The docs do suggest there is an 'AddStatement' method on the PowerShell class, but it's not there in reality.

Or am I better just putting it all in a script and just calling that from my C# instead?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's twigged. Basically break it down into loads of little individual calls. The Invoke method returns a collection of PSObject, which will be the result of the command, and you can then feed them into the next command as parameters/arguments etc.

Comment: AddStatement is in PowerShell v3 (still in CTP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AddStatement is only in the PowerShell v3 CTP (which is not production ready yet)

It's actually simpler than you think. That line should be treated as a script. A script doesn't neccessarily mean a physical ps1 file. Use the AddScript method:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Commands.AddScript("$myvariable = New-PSSessionOption ...");
ps.Invoke();
```

Comment: Just to add a bit to this, I was also struggling with creating a powershell script (via C#) that created a PSCredential object. This takes a username and password as constructor args, which (at least I don't think) you can do using the AddScript method. You can build up a string, but the password is a SecureString object, which you can't build into a string - needs to be passed as the object itself. But, Just realised that the API has an object called PSCredential. You can just construct using the API in C# (new PSCredential("username", password) (password is the result of a previous PS call).